# AMD processor has compatibility with QGIS and Grass GIS?

Tags: qgis, r, grass-gis

I would like to ask if the processors AMD are compatible with Q GIS, GRASS GIS as well as Rstudio. Until now I had Intel i5 and I would like to go to AMD Ryzen™ 7

Comment: Sure, they do not depend on the processor (unless you use a quantum processor).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Just so you can rest assured, I use qgis and grass, among many, on a pc with ryzen 7, as mentioned, it does not depend on the processor but on the operating system

Comment: Τhank you for your help

Comment: @ElioDiaz it *does* also depend on the processor, but these processors are instruction-set compatible. Other processors (eg some of the ARM chips, or the things Apple are now making) don't have the same instruction set and so binaries will not work there (sometimes non-compatible code can run via a translation layer or virtual machine system).